# Are there shortcuts for page down and page up in firefox

Tags: keyboard

I dont have a page down or page up buttons on my keyboard, and i noticed ctr+down=end ctr+up=home (at least in firefox)

Are there shortcuts for page down and page up?

(keyboard does not have a fn key like a macbook)

- Solution(firefox only):
- space=pageDown & shit+space=pageUp

Comment: @AliRezaMosajjal Don't think this is dupe of that as solution says `fn` key and OP states keyboard does not have a fn key like a macbook

Comment: yes it was my mistake, didn't understand the question very well. I'll delete my comment

Comment: @markkirby Although the suggested duplicate has accepted answer from a Mac user, there's another answer there with `xbindkeys`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>space</kbd> bar for page down, and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> for page up.